# flutter android main function is called twice

Tags: android, flutter

In my flutter application i noticed that main function is executing two times. I am using sample code from counter application. Text `main function` is printed twice. My AndroidManifest.xml is below

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.app.chat">

    <application android:label="rosta" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">


        <service android:name="io.wazo.callkeep.VoiceConnectionService" android:exported="true" android:label="Wazo" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE" tools:ignore="IntentFilterExportedReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:exported="true">
                <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:showWhenLocked="true" android:turnScreenOn="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
         
            <meta-data android:exported="true" android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
           
            <meta-data android:exported="true" android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable" android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
            <intent-filter android:exported="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="high_importance_channel" />

        
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Below is counter application code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  print('main functions');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        //

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          //

          //

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue once in a flutter project and noticed it was due to a dependency which had a background service which led to a second call of the flutter main function. Maybe you have such a dependency (like i.e. the ConnectionService in your manifest), that is calling the main function.

You could try removing such possible dependency candidates and check the behavior again.

Comment: how did u find which dependency is causing the main() to be called twice? I am facing the same issue but in iOS not in android in my current project and it contains too many dependencies.

Comment: It was caused by a dependency for audio services

Answer (score 2):

In case you recently face this issue where your `main()` function is getting called twice and you use `firebase_messaging` version `14.1.0` you should upgrade your package version to `14.1.2`.

See https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9912