# Flutter main() is firing twice

Tags: flutter

**Update: The whole of `main.dart` is being called twice.**

```
var x = 0;
void main() {
  print(++x);
}
```

Prints '1' to the log twice.

---

On Android and Flutter Web (I haven't tested other platforms yet), the entry function to my application, `main()` is firing twice and I can't figure out what the problem is.

I've gone so far as to take RunApp() out of main(), stripping it down to just:

```
void main() {
  print(StackTrace.current);
}
```

The output is, printing twice:

```
I/flutter ( 8417): #0      main (package:appname/main.dart:14:20)
I/flutter ( 8417): #1      _runMain.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:134:23)
I/flutter ( 8417): #2      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
I/flutter ( 8417): #3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
I/flutter ( 8417): #0      main (package:appname/main.dart:14:20)
I/flutter ( 8417): #1      _runMain.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:134:23)
I/flutter ( 8417): #2      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
I/flutter ( 8417): #3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

Naturally, this means that every component of startup happens twice, particularly API communication for session restoration.

I've tried

- searching the entire directory for calls to `main()`
- resetting the android directory to stock
- `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`
- deleting **build**

I've searched for this, but most results are about FutureBuilder or build(). I did find this [unanswered similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72542701/flutter-android-main-function-is-called-twice#comment130034509_72542701)

There is nothing special about my Configuration either

[image]

Comment: Is this only in debug mode? I'm thinking if it could be because of hot reload. Maybe also check if it happens when running from terminal via 'flutter run' instead of the IDE

Comment: It happens any time I press the Run button. It also happens via `flutter run` Thank you

Comment: @dumazy In my case, it was caused by https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, it was caused by [the audio service package](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service). I'll bring this to their attention.

Comment: 100% reproducible that removing audio_service fixes the problem!